# What is the error in this while loop?

Tags: java

I'm modeling a while loop after an old piece of code I have, since I somewhat forgot how to do it. Here's the old piece:

```
    Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Q1 = s2.nextDouble();
            while (Q1 < 1 || Q1 > 5) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("ERROR: Please enter a number between 1 and 5.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println(question1);
                Q1 = s2.nextDouble();
            }
```

It's fairly simple. Here's the piece I'm writing now:

```
System.out.println("Welcome to " + appName + "!");
System.out.println("To begin, please select a username.");

Scanner usernameScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String username = usernameScanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Your username will be " + username + ".");
System.out.println("Is that correct?");

while(username.length() < 3){
    System.out.println("Error: Your username must be more than 3 characters.");
    System.out.println("Please select a username.");
    String username = usernameScanner.nextLine();

}
```

I'm getting an error telling me this:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Duplicate local variable username"

I thought it would be simple to fix, but I'm confused. Aren't I redefining a local variable in the first piece? Why doesn't it work in the second?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've defined username twice. Once outside the loop, once inside the loop. Declare type once, use variable name otherwise.

Comment: Why were you even executing the code when there was a compile error? Pay attention to the compiler - fix all errors before you try to execute the code, otherwise you are guaranteed to get that exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the loop `while(username.length() < 3)`, the line `String username = usernameScanner.nextLine();` needs to be changed to `username = usernameScanner.nextLine();`. Instead of modifying the value in `username`, you were declaring a new variable with the same name, causing the error.